# Dynamic signal creation in VHDL and solution of VHDL error: Syntax error near "process"

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to the world of VHDL and I'm getting this error saying Syntax error near process. I checked for the solutions and found that there may be a missing end if statement but in my code I'm not having that problem.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
use STD.textio.all;

entity Main_Architecture is
port(
    SEN: out std_logic;
    reset: in std_logic;
    clk: in std_logic
    );
end Main_Architecture;

architecture Behavioral of Main_Architecture is
signal main_counter : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)  := "00000000";
signal mux: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";
signal output  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal main_counter_int : integer range 0 to 127:=0;
signal main_generator : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);


begin
process(main_counter,reset,clk)
    variable x: std_logic;
    variable y: std_logic;
    variable z: integer;
begin
    if(reset = '1') then
        main_counter <= (others => '0');
    end if;

    if(clk'event and clk='1') then

        if(mux="00") then                               --load main counter
            y:= main_counter(0);
            x:= (main_counter(0)XOR main_counter(6) XOR main_counter(7));
            main_counter(7 downto 1) <= main_counter(6 downto 0);
            main_counter(0)<=x;
            main_counter <= main_counter+'1';
            output(0)<=y;
            output(1)<=main_counter(0);
            output(2)<=main_counter(1);
            output(3)<=main_counter(2);
            output(4)<=main_counter(3);
            output(5)<=main_counter(4);
            output(6)<=main_counter(5);
            main_counter_int<=conv_integer(output);
            if(main_counter >= "11111111") then
                mux <= "01";
            end if;
        end if;

        if(mux="01") then
            if(main_counter_int < 2) then
                z:=1;
            else if(main_counter_int < 4) then
                z:=2;
            else if(main_counter_int < 8) then
                z:=3;
            else if(main_counter_int < 16) then
                z:=4;
            else if(main_counter_int < 32) then
                z:=5;
            else if(main_counter_int < 64) then
                z:=6;
            else if(main_counter_int < 128) then
                z:=7;
            end if;


        end if;

    end if;

end process;    -------- LINE 104  -------

end Behavioral;
```

Also I want to create a std_logic_vector which has a size from value z to 0. i.e. A vector of size z+1. How can i make it?

Comment: You can use unconstrained arrays and generics to get self-sizing vectors but they must evaluate to a fixed size after elaboration. You can get truly dynamic vectors with access types but they are not synthesizable if that is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Question part 1

Without looking into any other issues in your code, I think the problem is this section, which I have re-formatted to show how many 'end if' statements you are missing:

```
    if(mux="01") then
        if(main_counter_int < 2) then
            z:=1;
        else
            if(main_counter_int < 4) then
                z:=2;
            else
                if(main_counter_int < 8) then
                    z:=3;
                else
                    if(main_counter_int < 16) then
                        z:=4;
                    else
                        if(main_counter_int < 32) then
                            z:=5;
                        else
                            if(main_counter_int < 64) then
                                z:=6;
                            else
                                if(main_counter_int < 128) then
                                    z:=7;
                                end if;


    end if;
```

I think you probably wanted to use `elsif` instead of `else if`.

### Question part 2

For the second part of your question, assuming you want to produce code that can be realised in hardware, there is no such thing as a run-time sized std_logic_vector. The best you can do is to make your vector have the maximum size that it could need, then only assign or use parts of it, based on the value of 'z'.

### A couple of other points:

```
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
```

This is not a 'true' standard library, and there are many other answers where people recommend against using this library. If you need to perform math functions (e.g. `+`), `USE ieee.numeric_std.all;`, then create signals of type signed or unsigned. In your example, `main_counter` would be declared `signal main_counter : unsigned(7 downto 0)  := "00000000";`. Operations like `+` can then be performed on this signal, with no ambiguity as to whether it is supposed to be signed or not.

Lastly, the section:

```
        output(0)<=y;
        output(1)<=main_counter(0);
        output(2)<=main_counter(1);
        output(3)<=main_counter(2);
        output(4)<=main_counter(3);
        output(5)<=main_counter(4);
        output(6)<=main_counter(5);
```

could more compactly be written using the concatenation operator `&` as

```
        output(6 downto 0) <= main_counter(5 downto 0) & y;
```

Side note: output(7) doesn't seem to ever be assigned.

Comment: Ditto the separate "if" statements for "reset" and "clk". Roll them into one "if ... elsif" statement.

Comment: Further more having the signal `main_counter` in the sensitivity list of the process doesn't add anything substantial to the function described by the code, thus it should be removed.