# Expecting type void, Syntax error near "process" with transport delay code - vhdl error transport

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I'm new to FPGA and I'm trying to code a simple demo with transport delay. but I got the following errors:

```
1.ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "../PGAND2.vhd" Line 54: Syntax error near "process".
2.ERROR:HDLCompiler:841 - "../PGAND2.vhd" Line 55: Expecting type  void for <behavioral>.
```

I'm confused about this and I can't solve this. Could you please give me some tips to solve this, thanks a lot! Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity PGAND2 is
    generic( trise : TIME := 1ns ;
            tfall : TIME := 1ns ) ;
    port(   a0 : in std_logic ;
        a1 : in std_logic ;
        z0 : out std_logic ) ;
end PGAND2;

architecture Behavioral of PGAND2 is

begin
process ( a1, a0) 
    variable zdf :std_logic ;
    begin 
        zdf := a1 AND a0 ;
        if zdf = '1' then
            z0 <= transport zdf after trise ;
        else if zdf = '0' then
            z0 <= transport zdf after tfall ;
        else
            z0 <= transport zdf ;
    end if ;
    end process ;
end Behavioral;
```

The environment is ISE 14.7 on Windows 10.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Duplicate. Yet another `else if/elseif/elsif` mistake, we're running about 2 a week at the moment. Xilinx ALWAYS gives the same confusing syntax error when it sees "end process" instead of "end if". Somebody ought to publish a basic syntax reference for VHDL or something. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567501/vhdl-syntax-error-with-if-then-process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689073/dynamic-signal-creation-in-vhdl-and-solution-of-vhdl-error-syntax-error-near-p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171924/accumulator-in-vhdl#comment83323359_48171924

Comment: Thanks so much, Brian! I thought it was something wrong with transport delay sentence, totally wrong direction! I have replaced "else if" with "elsif", and the problem is fixed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **if then else** statement format in VHDL like below:

```
if [condition] then 
   [statements]
else 
   [statements]
end if;
```

And then **else if** statement is not **elsif** so
**else if** statement itself needs **end if** keyword.

You should use ***elsif*** keyword or ***else if ... then ... end if*** statement.

The correct code for your description is :

```
process( a1, a0) 
    variable zdf :std_logic ;
begin 
    zdf := a1 AND a0 ;
    if zdf = '1' then
        z0 <= transport zdf after trise ;
    elsif zdf = '0' then
        z0 <= transport zdf after tfall ;
    else
        z0 <= transport zdf ;
    end if ;
end process ;
```

Or

```
process( a1, a0) 
    variable zdf :std_logic ;
begin 
    zdf := a1 AND a0 ;
    if zdf = '1' then
        z0 <= transport zdf after trise ;
    else if zdf = '0' then
        z0 <= transport zdf after tfall ;
        end if;
    else
        z0 <= transport zdf ;
    end if ;
end process ;
```

Comment: Or you could consider a case statement.... For this case I would never suggest to use "else if" like you suggest.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply! I'll be careful of the use of “else if/elsif” statement.